# Question about fibers in Win32 documentation

Tags: winapi

I'm not really understanding the following description about fibers in Microsoft's Win32 documentation:

> a fiber assumes the identity of the thread that runs it. For example, if a fiber accesses thread local storage (TLS), it is accessing the thread local storage of the thread that is running it.

What does "assumes the identity of the thread" in the first sentence mean? Can anyone explain this sentence in other way?

Comment: A fiber runs on a thread, so any operations that are thread-dependent will use the thread that the fiber happens to be running on at the time. TLS, impersonation, the thread ID, thread priority, etc.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that fibers turned out not to have been a good idea and all the programs that ever used them changed course and don't anymore.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you. so "a fiber assumes the identity of the thread that runs it" means " a fiber have certain property of thread that runs it " Can i interpreted in this way?

Comment: It is a confusing sentence. It should just say "From a system standpoint, any thread-dependent operation performed by a fiber is performed on the thread the fiber is running on."

Comment: a fiber is associated with the thread that the fiber is running on.

Comment: The documentation has been updated. It now says "operations performed by a fiber are considered to have been performed by the thread that runs it."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan care to elaborate? afaik they are very much in use in game engines for example.. recent console APIs do offer support for them too, etc. what does "turned out not to have been a good idea" mean exactly?